# Search Windows Explorer folder for Word documents with superscript

Tags: ms-word, windows-explorer

I have a folder of hundreds of Word documents. Is there a way to use the Explorer search function to identify any document that has a superscript character?

Comment: Do you mean that the document contains a character formatted using superscript or just the filename? Would you also want to search metadata of the document?

Comment: Correct, the document contains a character formatted in superscript. If the metadata would have this information, yes.